# Is there any way to change the PopUp property on forms in Microsoft Access with VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access, popup

I want to give people the option of running an Access 2016 database in one of two ways.

**1.** Single window, tabbed. This is the default in Access and avoids creating a bunch of separate windows. This is achieved by leaving the property "PopUp" on forms set to false/no.

**2.** Multi-window mode, with only the main navigation form staying in the main Access window.

Some people prefer single window tabbed mode, and some people prefer multi-window mode. I thought it was going to be easy to implement this simply by using VBA in "On Form Load" but when I try `Me.PopUp = True`, I get an error.

> Run-time error '2136':
>   To set this property, open the form or report in Design view.

Is there any way I can get around this limitation to modify `Me.PopUp` with VBA, or some other properties that I can change with VBA that will cause a form to pop up as a new tab or a new window based on a global variable being set to true or false?

Answer (score 1):

With database set for Tabbed Documents, open form or report in popup mode by using acDialog parameter in WindowMode argument of OpenForm.

If you want to use a global variable as a test for whether or not to use popup, declare variable in a general module, set it when main form opens, then use it in IIf().

`Docmd.OpenForm "MyForm", , , , , IIf(gblMode = "Pop", acDialog, "")`

Beware, global variables lose value if any code breaks on run-time error. Alternatives are TempVars or set a textbox on form that never closes.

Comment: acDialog causes the window to be modal, which prevents people from having more than one form open at a time. The reason I want windowed mode is so people who want to can have multiple windows side by side. Thanks for the tip about TempVars though, I didn't know there was an alternative to global variables other than hidden text boxes which I try to avoid because it feels messy.

Comment: I have no problem opening a form with acDialog then a button on that form opens another form with acDialog. Yes, they are modal and can interact with only top one. I don't think you can get everything you want.